# saveScrollPosition with unique form id

Tags: php, javascript

Im using the following (seemingly common) method to save scroll position on submit in a php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- script for scroll position on submit -->
    function saveScrollPositions(theForm) {
    if(theForm) {
    var scrolly = typeof window.pageYOffset != 'undefined' ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var scrollx = typeof window.pageXOffset != 'undefined' ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    theForm.scrollx.value = scrollx;
    theForm.scrolly.value = scrolly;
    }
    }
</script>   
</head>



<body>
    <form id="ReportForm<?php echo $userNumber; ?>" name="ReportForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" onsubmit="return saveScrollPositions(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="scrollx" id="scrollx" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="scrolly" id="scrolly" value="0" />

      -- various form controls here --

    </form>


<?php
    $scrollx = 0;
    $scrolly = 0;
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['scrollx'])) {
    $scrollx = $_REQUEST['scrollx'];
    }
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['scrolly'])) {
    $scrolly = $_REQUEST['scrolly'];
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo(<?php echo "$scrollx" ?>, <?php echo "$scrolly" ?>);
</script>
</body>
```

In the body the form is wrapped by a repeat region to get multiple reports from a database, but each form in the loaded page at runtime needs a unique id, so in the form tag i have:

```
id="reportForm<?php echo $userNumber ?>"
```

which causes the saveScrollPositions to fail. Removing the userNumber that is tacked on to the end works. Any idea how i can fix this?

I very much appreciate any help you can offer on this and thank you in anticipation.

Kind regards,
John

Comment: Can you use Class for your saveScrollPositions() versus the Id? `class="formSection" id="reportForm<?php echo $userNumber; ?>"`

Comment: How are you calling `saveScrollPositions`? Assigning unique ID shouldn't be a problem -- actually it doesn't really matters whether the form has an ID or not.

Comment: Hi Guys - thanks for your response. Class versus id doesnt work. I dont get why it shouldnt work with id as it's not being referred to anywhere .. as Passerby suggests, it doesnt really need an id to work. I have updated my post above to include all the code for the savescrollposition

Comment: If you're calling this function in HTML `onsubmit`, you may want to `return true;` at the end of the function: `<script>function trap(f){...return true;}</script><form onsubmit="return trap(this);">`.

Comment: I couldn't get the 'return true' to work. After further probing i remembered the reason i needed a unique form id was for form validation with a couple of <input> controls. I have now removed the js validation and gone with required="required" which works in the browsers i need it to work in :) With that, i have removed the unique id from the form and now saveScrollPosition works again. It didnt 'fix' the issue but it's a different approach that works for me. Thanks guys!